# "Missing app.json" when start an expo project, while the app.json already exists

Tags: android, expo

I try run a blank project from hours, and I do not understand what is wrong.

I have the file app.json in my project folder :

```
{
"sdkVersion" : "19.0.0"
}
```

and when I try :

```
expo start
```

I have this message :

```
PS D:\Projects\VSCode\AwesomeProject> expo start
Starting project at D:\Projects\VSCode\AwesomeProject
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
No Expo configuration found. Are you sure this is a project directory?
PS D:\Projects\VSCode\AwesomeProject>
```

If I try

```
expo android
```

I get this :

```
PS D:\Projects\VSCode\AwesomeProject> expo android
Error: Missing app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/
There is an error with your project. See above logs for   information.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
- Making sure project is set up correctly...
PS D:\Projects\VSCode\AwesomeProject>
```

This is a blank project, i do not understand what is going wrong. How can I found sdkversion in use ? I thought It was the error, but I am not sure.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

looks like that was generated with react-native init and not expo, because it doesn't have an "expo" section. we should provide a better error message in this case.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0"
    ...
  }
}
```

It's part of the project I just made.

Comment: no, it was not generated by react native. I tried to add expo comment, but it is not permitted by the compilation. Well, I started a new project and I am fine now. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: image add sdkVersion]

I solved this problem by adding sdkVersion, as you can see in the image